# Raw text strings for file paths in R

Tags: r, string

Is it possible to use a prefix when specifying a filepath string in R to ignore escape characters?

For example if I want to read in the file `example.csv` when using windows, I need to manually change `\` to `/` or `\\`. For example,

```
'E:\DATA\example.csv'
```

becomes

```
'E:/DATA/example.csv'

data <- read.csv('E:/DATA/example.csv')
```

In `python` I can prefix my string using `r` to avoid doing this (e.g. `r'E:\DATA\example.csv'`). Is there a similar command in `R`, or an approach that I can use to avoid having this problem. (I move between windows, mac and linux - this is just a problem on the windows OS obviously).

Comment: be sure to jump to the recent answer -- all answers prior to R 4.0 needed workarounds which are no longer needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61672183/3576984

Comment: +1, @djq since you're still active, consider accepting Caleb Fitzgerald's answer. it is now burried down and already prompted a duplicate answer.

Comment: Done - thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is now possible with R version 4.0.0. See [`?Quotes`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html) for more.

*Example*

```
r"(c:\Program files\R)"
## "c:\\Program files\\R"
```

Comment: Note that you can also use `r"[]"` and `r"{}"`.

Comment: And if that's not enough, you can add any number of dashes: `r"--{This string has "quotes" and {brackets}}--"`. Just keep adding dashes until the terminating sequence is no longer contained in the string!

Answer (score 43):

You can use `file.path` to construct the correct file path, independent of operating system.

```
file.path("E:", "DATA", "example.csv")
[1] "E:/DATA/example.csv"
```

It is also possible to convert a file path to the canonical form for your operating system, using `normalizePath`:

```
zz <- file.path("E:", "DATA", "example.csv")
normalizePath(zz)
[1] "E:\\DATA\\example.csv"
```

---

But in direct response to your question: I am not aware of a way to ignore the escape sequence using R.  In other words, I do not believe it is possible to copy a file path from Windows and paste it directly into R.

However, if what you are really after is a way of copying and pasting from the Windows Clipboard and get a valid R string, try `readClipboard`

For example, if I copy a file path from Windows Explorer, then run the following code, I get a valid file path:

```
zz <- readClipboard()
zz
[1] "C:\\Users\\Andrie\\R\\win-library\\"
```

Comment: must be possible to reverse enginer readClipboard and create a function that does what op asks?

Answer (score 10):

1. If `E:\DATA\example.csv` is on the clipboard then do this:

   ```
    example.csv <- scan("clipboard", what = "")
    ## Read 1 item
    example.csv
    ## [1] "E:\\DATA\\example.csv"
   ```

Now you can copy `"E:\\DATA\\example.csv"` from the above output above onto the clipboard and then paste that into your source code if you need to hard code the path.

Similar remarks apply if `E:\DATA\example.csv` is in a file.

2. If the file exists then another thing to try is:

   example.csv <- file.choose()

and then navigate to it and continue as in 1) above (except the `file.choose` line replaces the `scan` statement there).

3. Note that its not true that you need to change the backslashes to forward slashes for `read.csv` on Windows but if for some reason you truly need to do that translation then if the file exists then this will translate backslashes to forward slashes (but if it does not exist then it will give an annoying warning so you might want to use one of the other approaches below):

   normalizePath(example.csv, winslash = "/")

and these translate backslashes to forward slashes even if the file does not exist:

```
gsub("\\", "/", example.csv, fixed = TRUE)
## [1] "E:/DATA/example.csv"
```

or

```
chartr("\\", "/", example.csv)
## [1] "E:/DATA/example.csv"
```

4. In 4.0+ the following syntax is supported.  ?Quotes discusses additional variations.

   ```
    r"{E:\DATA\example.csv}"
   ```

EDIT: Added more info on `normalizePath`.
EDIT: Added (4).

Comment: +1 Because this is pretty much what I said in my answer. Note that `normalizePath` works even if the file doesn't exist, in which case a warning is issued.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible with R versions before 4.0.0. Sorry.

Comment: Although I fear on this occasion you are correct, I have learnt from bitter experience to never say that anything is impossible in R.

Comment: In this case the only possibility seems to involve quite a change to some of the R source code. You could implement something just like Python's raw string thing, but you'd have to tweak the grammar. You'd probably break stuff....

Comment: Another possibility would be some kind of source filter. But it wouldn't really be R then, I think.

Comment: I think it is-- it requires some cheating with `sep` arguments in `read.table`, but it's definitely possible.

Comment: Never say never indeed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61672183/3576984

Answer (score 4):

A slightly different approach I use with a custom made function that takes a windows path and corrects it for R.

```
pathPrep <- function() {                        
    cat("Please enter the path:\\n\\n")         
    oldstring <- readline()                     
    chartr("\\\\", "/", oldstring)              
}
```

Let's try it out!

When prompted paste the path into console or use ctrl + r on everything at once

```
(x <- pathPrep())                      
C:/Users/Me/Desktop/SomeFolder/example.csv
```

Now you can feed it to a function

```
shell.exec(x) #this piece would work only if    
              #  this file really exists in the 
              #  location specified
```

But as others pointed out what you want is not truly possible.

Comment: Thanks @Tyler, maybe I should clarify that I am also interested in workarounds so this is very useful; I suspected that it was not possible to do by default.

Comment: @celenius  I hope what you want is possible because I've wanted it for some time. : )  But this was the closest I could get. :(

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but for people stumbling upon this question in recent times, wanted to share that with the latest version R4.0.0, it is possible to parse in raw strings. The syntax for that is `r"()"`. Note that the string goes in the brackets.

Example:

```r
> r"(C:\Users)"
[1] "C:\\Users"
```

Source: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html
jump to section: significant user-visible changes.

Comment: Thanks but Caleb Fitzgerald had given this answer a couple month before you did

Answer (score 2):

Here's an incredibly ugly one-line hack to do this in base R, with no packages necessary:

```
setwd(gsub(", ", "", toString(paste0(read.table("clipboard", sep="\\", stringsAsFactors=F)[1,], sep="/"))))
```

Usable in its own little wrapper function thus (using `suppressWarnings` for peace of mind):

```
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/username1/Documents"
> change_wd=function(){
+   suppressWarnings(setwd(gsub(", ", "", toString(paste0(read.table("clipboard", sep="\\", stringsAsFactors=F)[1,], sep="/")))))
+   getwd()
+ }
```

Now you can run it:

```
#Copy your new folder path to clipboard
> change_wd()
[1] "C:/Users/username1/Documents/New Folder"
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the actual question of "Can I parse raw-string in R without having to double-escape backslashes?" which is a good question, and has a lot of uses besides the specific use-case with the clipboard.

I have found a package that appears to provide this functionality:

https://github.com/trinker/pathr

See "win_fix". 
The use-case specified in the docs is exactly the use-case you just stated, however I haven't investigated whether it handles more flexible usage scenarios yet.