# How to manipulate file path in R?

Tags: python, r, path, formatting

I often use windows to copy and paste file paths into R scripts, which results in something like the following:

```
file = 'C:\this\is\a\test.tif'
```

However, this results in an error and I have to manually switch the path seperators from `\` to `/`

```
>file = 'C:\this\is\a\test.tif'
Error: '\i' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'C:\this\i"
```

If I were using Python, I would simply use the following to format the path correctly:

```
file = r'C:\this\is\a\test.tif'
```

Is there a similar R method to Python's raw string `r''` method to quickly format paths?

Comment: Unfortunately R does not support raw strings. A workaround may be with `scan`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11812540/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Raw text strings for file paths in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197027/raw-text-strings-for-file-paths-in-r)

Comment: You can use RStudio's snippet feature to make pasting Windows paths less painful. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39989341/3827849

Comment: @BlueMagister From R 4.0.0 raw strings are supported. See [Escaping backslash () in string or paths in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185287/escaping-backslash-in-string-or-paths-in-r/63078969#63078969)

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing that I can think of to the raw string read when working from the R command line is to use the `scan` function:

```
> tmp <- scan(what='')
1: 'C:\this\is\a\test.tif'
2: 
Read 1 item
> tmp
[1] "C:\\this\\is\\a\\test.tif"
>
```

or

```
> tmp <- scan(what='',n=1)
1: C:\this\is\a\test.tif
Read 1 item
> tmp
[1] "C:\\this\\is\\a\\test.tif"
> cat(tmp, '\n')
c:\this\is\a\test.tif
```

The `scan` function will prompt for input from the console, you can type or paste what you want there and the printing of `tmp` in this case shows that the backslashes were interpreted literally (so print shows them doubled and cat shows them as is).

Comment: It's all right in console.But how to input filepath in code editor?

Comment: If working in a code editor, paste it as is, then use the find and replace functionality of the editor.  Or read it once using the console, then use the `dput` function to create a version to paste into the editor.