# Are there raw strings in R for regular expressions?

Tags: regex, r

In Python you can use raw strings:

```
import re
re.sub(r"\\", ":", "back\\slash")  # r"\\" instead of "\\\\"
```

Does this exist in **R** as well? For example, here is an equivalent code snippet without raw strings in **R**:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace("back\\slash", "\\\\", ":")
```

I would love to be able to do this:

```
str_replace("back\\slash", raw("\\"), ":")
```

Does this functionality already exist, or should I just implement my own function `raw()`?

Comment: I think you can use `[]`

Comment: I don;t think so - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197027/raw-text-strings-for-file-paths-in-r

Comment: For regex purposes: `sub("\\", ":", "back\\slash", fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: `sub("[\\]", ":","back\\slash")`and `sub("\\", ":","back\\slash", fixed = TRUE)` both work

Comment: @MichaelChirico Easier to read and write the patterns

Comment: I think a better example would be how to write `"\\w+\\s+\\d+"` as `raw("\w+\s+\d+")`. Just a backslash is "ambiguous".

Comment: Exactly. I just like the 4 slash `"\\\\"` example to show how things can get out of hand quickly

Comment: This is known as "Leaning Toothpick Syndrome": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome

Answer (score 53):

As of R 4.0.0 this is available.

> Raw character constants are also available using a syntax similar to
> the one used in C++: `r"(...)"` with `...` any character
> sequence, except that it must not contain the closing sequence
> `)"`. The delimiter pairs `[]` and `{}` [c]an also be
> used. For  additional flexibility, a number of dashes can be placed
> between the opening quote and the opening delimiter, as long as the same
> number of dashes appear between the closing delimiter and the closing quote.

From the example in `?Quotes`:

```
r"{(\1\2)}"
## [1] "(\\1\\2)"
```

(note, the double-backslashes are R's printed representation of backslashes: `cat()` on this object will print `(\1\2)`)

From @Mael in comments: to solve the OP's original question,

```r
stringr::str_replace("back\\slash", r"(\\)", ":")
## or
gsub(r"(\\)", ":", "back\\slash")
```

(the latter is very close to Python's syntax)

Comment: This is good news that this is being discussed seriously or is under development and will be addressed in the foreseeable future.  Thanks for responding.  Perhaps this is too much to ask, but another "great simplifier" feature in Python that I find useful for its consistency and utility is the docstring object syntax, i.e., using balanced triple quote marks (""" docstring doublequote syntax """ or ''' docstring single quote syntax ''') for multi-line comments and internal documentation strings.  I'll have to request it from the R core language developers.

Comment: The `r-devel@r-project.org` mailing list is the right place to raise such requests. (Note, R at present doesn't have such a convention for "internal documentation strings" - although I would argue that the roxygen(2) system is fuller-featured than Python docstrings ...)

Comment: Sadly, this does not fix when passing regex in SQL to, in my case, Athena.

Comment: As per OP's example, one should do: `str_replace("back\\slash", r"(\\)", ":")`

Comment: `r"--[ ... ]--"` This is valid too.

Answer (score 2):

For your example a R < 4.0.0 alternative would be the other way round to use a function that automatically escapes special characters. Here the `stringi` package is helpful.

```
library(stringr)
library(stringi)
str_replace("back\\slash", stri_escape_unicode("\\"), ":")
```

Since this is very verbose defining `r <- stri_escape_unicode` would come close to your desired functionality (`r("\\")`).

The `stringi` package also has a function to reverse escaping `stri_unescape_unicode` which is useful in a shiny apps, where user inputs are automatically escaped.