# dplyr filter on a vector rather than a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr

This seems like a simple question, but I have not come across a clean solution for it yet. I have a vector in R and I want to remove certain elements from the vector, however I want to avoid the vector[vector != "thiselement"] notation for a variety of reasons. In particular, here is what I am trying to do:

```
# this doesnt work
all_states = gsub(" ", "-", tolower(state.name)) %>% filter("alaska")

# this doesnt work either
all_states = gsub(" ", "-", tolower(state.name)) %>% filter(!= "alaska")

# this does work but i want to avoid this approach to filtering
all_states = gsub(" ", "-", tolower(state.name))
all_states = all_states[all_states != "alaska"]
```

can this be done in a simple manner? Thanks in advance for the help!

EDIT - the reason I'm struggling with this is because I'm only finding things online regarding filtering based on a column of a dataframe, for example:

```
my_df %>% filter(col != "alaska")
```

however I'm working with a vector not a dataframe here

Comment: i just want to become more comfortable using dplyr to write cleaner code. I can technically do this with a 1-liner but it would have to be: 

all_states = gsub(" ", "-", tolower(state.name))[gsub(" ", "-", tolower(state.name)) != "alaska"]

Comment: the list is gonna be expanded to include other states, and your solution doesn't account for the formatting to the state names i'm doing either

Comment: The `d` in `dplyr` is for `data.frame`. "using dplyr to write cleaner code" should mean using `dplyr` for what it's made for (data frames) and not trying to use it when inappropriate (not data frames).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Update**

As [@r_31415](https://stackoverflow.com/users/460147/r-31415) noted in the comments, packages such as [`stringr`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/index.html) provide functions that can better address this question.

With [`str_subset(string, pattern, negate=FALSE)`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_subset.html), one could filter character vectors like

```r
library(stringr)

# Strings that have at least one character that is neither "A" nor "B".
> c("AB", "BA", "ab", "CA") %>% str_subset("[^AB]")
[1] "ab" "CA"


# Strings that do not include characters "A" or "B".
> c("AB", "BA", "ab", "CA") %>% str_subset("[AB]", negate=TRUE)
[1] "ab"
```

By default, the `pattern` is interpreted as a regular expression. Therefore, to search literal patterns that contains special characters like `(`, `*`, and `?`, one could enclose the pattern string with the modifier function [`fixed(literal_string)`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/modifiers.html) instead of escaping with [double-backslash escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491986/r-gsub-replacing-backslashes) or the [raw-string since R 4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688880/are-there-raw-strings-in-r-for-regular-expressions)

```r
# escape special character with "\\" (has to escape `\` with itself in a string literal).
> c("(123.5)", "12345") %>% str_subset("\\(123\\.5\\)")
[1] "(123.5)"

# R 4.0.0 supports raw-string, which is handy for regex strings
> c("(123.5)", "12345") %>% str_subset(r"{\(123\.5\)}")
[1] "(123.5)"

# use the fixed() modifier
> c("(123.5)", "12345") %>% str_subset(fixed("(123.5)"))
[1] "(123.5)"


## unexpected results if without escaping or the "fixed()" modifier
> c("(123.5)", "12345") %>% str_subset("(123.5)")
[1] "(123.5)" "12345"
```

---

**Original Answer**

Sorry for posting on a 5-month-old question to archive a simpler solution.

Package `dplyr` can filter character vectors in following ways:

```
> c("A", "B", "C", "D") %>% .[matches("[^AB]", vars=.)]
[1] "C" "D"
> c("A", "B", "C", "D") %>% .[.!="A"]
[1] "B" "C" "D"
```

The first approach allows you to filter with regular expression, and the second approach uses fewer words. It works because package `dplyr` imports package `magrittr` albeit masks its functions like `extract`, but not the placeholder `.`.

Details of placeholder `.` can be found on within help of [forward-pipe operator `%>%`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/magrittr.pdf), and this placeholder has mainly three usage:

> - Using the dot for secondary purposes
> - Using lambda expressions with %>%
> - Using the dot-place holder as lhs

Here we are taking advantage of its 3rd usage.

Comment: Is there a way to negate the first approach with "matches" ?

Comment: @Jens, one could negate via either indexing, such as `c("A", "B", "C", "D") %>% .[-matches("[^AB]", vars=.)] `, or regular expression itself, such as `c("A", "B", "C", "D") %>% .[matches("[AB]", vars=.)]` -- perhaps the caveats here is to prepend `-` instead of `!` to the `matches` selected indices for the negation, because `matches` returns an integer vector `c(3, 4)`, rather than a boolean mask `c(F, F, T, T)`.

Comment: Many thanks! I tried ! and it did not work. Now I know why. -matches worked

Comment: `c("A", "B", "C", "D") %>% str_subset("[^AB]")` ?

Comment: @r_31415 Indeed and thanks for the note! package `stringr` provides `str_subset("[AB]", negate=T)`, along with other useful string-related functions. It is a neat and modern approach to work with strings. Would you like to add it to the answer?

Comment: Maybe you can include it as an additional option in your own answer. Since it is already marked as the correct answer, more people will notice it in that way.

Comment: @r_31415 I have made an attempt, let me know if anything was missing :D

Comment: @Quar Very good and very comprehensive! :)

Answer (score 22):

You may like to try `magrittr::extract`. e.g.

```
> library(magrittr)

> c("A", "B", "C", "D") %>% extract(.!="A")
[1] "B" "C" "D"
```

For more `extract`-like functions load `magrittr` package and type `?alises`.

Comment: No documentation for ‘alises’ in specified packages and libraries:

Comment: It must've been removed in current version `?extract` works now.

Comment: very unfortunate that `tidyr` extract means a totally different thing. Love pipes, and this vector function is awesome!

Comment: This works not only with characters but also with numeric data, e.g. `vec %>% extract(.==123.45)`. So your suggestion works perfectly and is concise, too.

Comment: This perfectly captures the intent in the question. Should be the accepted answer imho.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure dplyr only really operates on data.frames.  Here's a two line example coercing the vector to a data.frame and back.

```
myDf = data.frame(states = gsub(" ", "-", tolower(state.name))) %>% filter(states != "alaska")
all_states = myDf$states
```

or a gross one liner:

```
all_states = (data.frame(states = gsub(" ", "-", tolower(state.name))) %>% filter(states != "alaska"))$states
```

Comment: got it. yeah maybe im making my life harder than it needs to be. okay thanks

Comment: yeah, it'd be nice to have 1 tool to use.  dplyr ends up looking a lot cleaner than the base R code in my opinion.  unfortunately it always ends up a mess with vectors.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to the desired result within the tidyverse is to put the vector into a tibble and then pull out the vector.

```
tibble(myvec = gsub(" ", "-", tolower(state.name))) %>% 
   filter(myvec != "alaska") %>% pull(myvec)
```

With the desired Output:
[1] "alabama"        "arizona"        "arkansas"       "california"        "colorado"  ...