# dplyr filter vector by position in pipe %>%

Tags: r, vector, dplyr, magrittr

From this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47259116/4083743) it is possible to filter a vector with `dplyr` in a pipe using `magrittr` package underneath like so:

```
library(dplyr)
c("D", "B", "C", "A", NA) %>% 
  .[matches("[^AB]", vars=.)]
#[1] "D" "C"

c("D", "B", "C", "A", NA) %>% 
  .[.!="A"]
# [1] "D" "B" "C" NA
```

But I would like to filter by vector position so if I wanted the first two positions I would get:

```
#[1] "D" "B"    #want to filter position <= 2
```

If I wanted 1st and 4th position I would get:

```
#[1] "D" "A"    #want to filter position by c(1, 4)
```

etc....

What is the best way to achieve this?

I thought using `row_number` might work but then remembered this wouldn't work as the sequence isn't right:

```
row_number(c("D", "B", "C", "A", NA))
# [1]  4  2  3  1 NA
```

I would be better using `seq_along`:

```
seq_along(c("D", "B", "C", "A", NA))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

But I'm not sure how to incorporate that in a pipe though.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "filtering" are not normally used to describe vector operations. Base R has a great tool for vector indexing/extracting: `[`

There is zero reason to involve the magrittr pipe here. `dplyr` verbs like `filter()` have no real world utility for vector operations, they are intended to be used exclusively for manipulating `tbl` objects.

In your examples you got tidyselect helpers involved, but that is insane overkill for doing basic positional matching.

```
> my_vector <- c("D", "B", "C", "A", NA)

> my_vector[c(1,2)]
[1] "D" "B"

> my_vector[c(1,4)]
[1] "D" "A"
```

Answer (score 2):

To filter a vector positionally using a `dplyr` pipe you could do this:

`c("D", "B", "C", "A", NA) %>% .[seq_along(.) %in% c(1,4)]`