# How to wrap R code that has quotes (both "" & '') to be text?

Tags: html, r, shiny

I have the following R code which has some markdown embedded.

```
  tab_header(    
    title = md(paste0(
      "<b>",
      '<span style="font-size: 11pt;">',input$title_num,'</span>',
      "<br>",
      '<span style="font-size: 11pt;">',input$title_name,'</span>',
      "</b>"))
  ) %>%
```

My goal is have this entire code chunk be converted to text. Whenever I have done this in the past, I would do something like this.

```
mytext <- "y=mx+b"

#which prints like this below
print(mytext)
[1] "y=mx+b"
```

But in this case I have html code where I am using both `""` and `''`.

Simply wrapping  `""` or `''` around the quote block will not work.

What is the best way to approach this?

I am trying to save this code through a `rendertext()` in my shiny app.

Desired goal:

```
mytext <- " tab_header(    
    title = md(paste0(
      "<b>",
      '<span style="font-size: 11pt;">',input$title_num,'</span>',
      "<br>",
      '<span style="font-size: 11pt;">',input$title_name,'</span>',
      "</b>"))
  ) %>% "

print(mytext)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of R 4.0.0, you can use raw text notation:

```
mytext <- r"[
tab_header(    
  title = md(paste0(
    "<b>",
    '<span style="font-size: 11pt;">',input$title_num,'</span>',
    "<br>",
    '<span style="font-size: 11pt;">',input$title_name,'</span>',
    "</b>"))
) %>% ]"

mytext
[1] "\ntab_header(    \n  title = md(paste0(\n    \"<b>\",\n    '<span style=\"font-size: 11pt;\">',input$title_num,'</span>',\n    \"<br>\",\n    '<span style=\"font-size: 11pt;\">',input$title_name,'</span>',\n    \"</b>\"))\n) %>% "
```

> Raw character constants are also available using a syntax similar to
> the one used in C++: r"(...)" with ... any character sequence, except
> that it must not contain the closing sequence )". The delimiter pairs
> [] and {} can also be used, and R can be used in place of r.

see `?Quotes` and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60342619/5224236)