# How to replace \\n with a space from dataframe column? (escape sequence)

Tags: r, dataframe, html-escape-characters

I am trying to replace all "\n" with a space in char strings in a column of data in R but not having much luck. (I also will need to get rid of all single backslashes with nothing but haven't made it that far yet.

An example of a row of column text is:

```
["Morals right down \\nthe drain?\"]
```

Here is my code:

```
df <- read.csv("Text.csv")
df <- df %>% select (text_info) #removing unwanted columns
```

The following doesn't work it doesn't do anything that I can see:

```
df  <-gsub("\\n", " ", df$text_info)
```

This almost works, but leaves one backslash:

```
df  <-gsub("\\\\n", " ", df$text_info)
```

Result: `["Morals right down \ the drain?\"]"]}`

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R 4.0.0 and later support [raw strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688880/are-there-raw-strings-in-r-for-regular-expressions), which gets around the sometimes confusing need to escape (or double escape) certain characters.

Raw strings are delineated by surrounding the string like so: `r'(my_string_here)'`. Applying this to your example:

```
text <- "Morals right down \\nthe drain?"

gsub(r'(\\n)', ' ', text)

[1] "Morals right down  the drain?"
```

Comment: I can't really tell if this works, it transforms it into a list, which i use df  <- data.frame(df) to transform it back into a dataframe, but it comes back as a df of 1 observation and 1 variable looking like the data is corrupted. Any clues?

Comment: Can you provide the first few rows of the data frame via `dput(head(df))`?

Comment: From your example, it looks like you're assigning the output of `gsub` to `df` itself, whereas I think you want to assign into `df$text_info`.

Comment: structure(list(df = "c(\"NULL\", \"NULL\", \"{\\\"4\\\":[\\\"[\\\\\\\"Morals right down \\\\\\\\nthe drain?\\\\\\\"]\\\"]}\"

Comment: I think you left off some of the `dput` output. It would be best if you could edit your original post to include it.

Comment: I got it finally! It took this, df$text_info  <- gsub(r'(\\\\n)', '', df$text_info), thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Great! If this answer worked for you, please mark it as correct, and optionally, upvote.

Comment: Done, I just can't upvote because I'm new :/