# Replace the first two characters of each string for every column in data frame

Tags: r, string, replace

I have a data frame which contains an unknown amount of columns. The data frame is generated from a previous step that delimits a string by '&'. The number of columns generated depends on the number & in the string. Irregardless of the number of columns, I need to remove the first two characters of the string if the string contains the a dash in the **5th** position. Whether the original columns get overwritten or the results are saved into new columns does not matter to me.

My data looks like this:

```
t3 <- c("2003-2342343","23-23490328","2024-23409")
t4 <- c("13-12","2013-23490","24-23409")
d <- data.frame(t3,t4)
```

I'm expecting the result to look like this (the 1st and 3rd element in t3 and 2nd element in t4 should change):

```
t3 <- c("03-2342343","23-23490328","24-23409")
t4 <- c("13-12","13-23490","24-23409")
d <- data.frame(t3,t4)
```

I'm using a loop to check the columns.

```
for(i in length(names(d))) {
  d[,i] <- if_else((which(strsplit(d[,i], "")[[1]]=="-")) == 5,sub('..', '', d[,i]),d[,i])
}
```

This is error message:

```
Error in `if_else()`:
! `true` must have size 1, not size 3.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Any ideas on what might be happening here?

I'm using R. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try also this:

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_remove(., "^\\d{2}(?=\\d{2}-)")))
```

`str_remove` takes only two arguments: the data and the pattern to remove. Here we define the pattern with a positive look-ahead `(?=\\d{2}-)`, which asserts that the two digits at string-start `^\\d{2}` must only be removed *iff* they are followed by two more digits plus a `-`

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I can confirm this works just as well as the previous one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `sub` in an `lapply`.

```
d[] <- lapply(d, sub, pat=r"{^\d{2}(?=\d{2}-)}", rep='', perl=TRUE)
d
#            t3       t4
# 1  03-2342343    13-12
# 2 23-23490328 13-23490
# 3    24-23409 24-23409
```

I use a [raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60342619/6574038) which is useful when playing around with [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) because then you don't have to escape the backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

We may use a regex method to capture the characters and remove - the pattern matched is the two characters (`..`) from the start (`^`) of the string followed by the next 3 characters captured as a group including the 5th character as `-` and in the replacement specify the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
d %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_replace(.x, "^..(..-)", "\\1")))
```

-output

```
       t3       t4
1  03-2342343    13-12
2 23-23490328 13-23490
3    24-23409 24-23409
```

---

Or in `base R` - a lot more compact with either `lapply`

```
d[] <- lapply(d, \(x) sub("^..(..-)", "\\1", x))
```

or convert to `matrix` and apply `sub` once all over the columns

```
d[] <- sub("^..(..-)", "\\1", as.matrix(d))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution.  The mutate across solution was not something I was aware of and that makes it so much simpler. I also didn't think of the regex pattern either so thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Another `sub` approach, but with pattern `.*?(.{2}-.*)`

```
> list2DF(lapply(d, function(s) sub(".*?(.{2}-.*)", "\\1", s)))
           t3       t4
1  03-2342343    13-12
2 23-23490328 13-23490
3    24-23409 24-23409
```

Comment: @akrun haha, sorry that I am used to `gsub`, but `sub` should be more straightforward here. Thanks! I have updated my answer.