# gsub catches only last character of group

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I have this character vector

```
vec <- c("(0,13.2]", "(13.2,28.3]", "(28.3,39.3]", "(39.3,49.4]", "(49.4,59.4]",
     "(59.4,69.3]", "(69.3,78.9]", "(78.9,87.8]", "(87.8,95.5]", "(95.5,100]")
```

and I want to change the entries to

```
expected <- c("0 to 13.2",  "13.2 to 28.3",  "28.3 to 39.3",  "39.3 to 49.4",  "49.4 to 59.4", 
     "59.4 to 69.3",  "69.3 to 78.9",  "78.9 to 87.8",  "87.8 to 95.5",  "95.5 to 100")
```

What I do is

```
vec %>%
  strsplit(., ",") %>%
  lapply(., function(level_i){
    from <- gsub("^\\(([0-9])+(\\.)*([0-9])*$", "\\1\\2\\3", level_i[1])
    to <- gsub("^([0-9])+(\\.)*([0-9])*]$", "\\1\\2\\3", level_i[2])
    paste0(from, " to ", to)
  }) %>%
  unlist()
# This gives:
# "0 to 3.2" "3.2 to 8.3" "8.3 to 9.3" "9.3 to 9.4" "9.4 to 9.4" "9.4 to 9.3" "9.3 to 8.9"
# "8.9 to 7.8" "7.8 to 5.5" "5.5 to 0"
```

My codes catches only the last element of a group, i.e. `"(0,13.2]"` becomes `"0 to 3.2"` and not `"0 to 13.2"`. How to catch all characters of a group?

Comment: You need to change `([0-9])+` to `([0-9]+)`. Notice in the former your group will only contain one digit and in the later multiple which is why you are getting only single digit

Comment: That was a small thing, don't think worth enough to post it as an answer. But Glad I could catch that small thing and make it work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `gsub` you can capture groups with `()`:

```r
gsub('\\((.*),(.*)\\]', "\\1 to \\2", vec)
#[1] "0 to 13.2"    "13.2 to 28.3" "28.3 to 39.3" "39.3 to 49.4" "49.4 to 59.4"
#[6] "59.4 to 69.3" "69.3 to 78.9" "78.9 to 87.8" "87.8 to 95.5" "95.5 to 100"
```

To capture exactly the digits instead of `.*`, you can do. This includes both integers and decimal formats:

```r
gsub('\\((\\d+[\\.]*\\d*),(\\d+[\\.]*\\d*)\\]', "\\1 to \\2", vec)
```

With all of those backlashes, you can simplify the regex with [raw strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60342619/13460602): `r"{\((\d+[\.]*\d*),(\d+[\.]*\d*)\]}"`

Comment: @IngoPingo you can use `\\d+`

Comment: you want `gsub('\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\]', "\\1 to \\2", vec)`

Comment: @IngoPingo the the + in \\d+ tells R that you want to find a digit 1 or more times. \\d* is similar, but can match zero times too

Comment: See edit, @IngoPingo, you can use `gsub('\\((\\d+[\\.]*\\d*),(\\d+[\\.]*\\d*)\\]', "\\1 to \\2", vec)`

Comment: @Maël That works. I wonder why I can't simply replace `\\d` with `[0-9]` which I usually use..

Comment: my bad! I gave a bad answer Ingo

Comment: @IngoPingo You can: try `gsub('\\(([0-9]+[\\.]*[0-9]*),([0-9]+[\\.]*[0-9]*)\\]', "\\1 to \\2", vec)`

Answer (score 2):

You can try the trick `read.table` + `trimws`

```
do.call(paste, c(
    read.table(text = trimws(vec, whitespace = "[\\(\\]]"), sep = ","),
    sep = " to "
))
```

which gives

```
 [1] "0 to 13.2"    "13.2 to 28.3" "28.3 to 39.3" "39.3 to 49.4" "49.4 to 59.4"
 [6] "59.4 to 69.3" "69.3 to 78.9" "78.9 to 87.8" "87.8 to 95.5" "95.5 to 100"
```

---

Another trick is `sub` + `trimws` + `chartr`

```
> sub(",", " to ", trimws(chartr("(]", "  ", vec)))
 [1] "0 to 13.2"    "13.2 to 28.3" "28.3 to 39.3" "39.3 to 49.4" "49.4 to 59.4"
 [6] "59.4 to 69.3" "69.3 to 78.9" "78.9 to 87.8" "87.8 to 95.5" "95.5 to 100"
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use gsub twice:

```
gsub("[^a-zA-Z0-9. ]", "", gsub(",", " to ", vec))
```

```
[1] "0 to 13.2"    "13.2 to 28.3" "28.3 to 39.3" "39.3 to 49.4" "49.4 to 59.4"
 [6] "59.4 to 69.3" "69.3 to 78.9" "78.9 to 87.8" "87.8 to 95.5" "95.5 to 100"
```