# How to prevent special characters being read in R?

Tags: r, string

In python its possible to prevent the strings being interpreted with special characters (such as `\t` or `\n`) by prepending the string with `r`, i.e.

```
    >>> file_string=r'D:\MPhil\Experiments\WafergenPlates\GSS2265ShortTGFbTimeCourseAffeymetrix\GSS2265\Raw_Data'
```

My questions is: What is the 'R' equivalent?

Comment: I don't think there is one.

Comment: Related (if not a dupe): [Raw text strings for file paths in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197027/raw-text-strings-for-file-paths-in-r)