# How to set working directory in R using command prompt?

Tags: r, netbeans, cmd

I am trying to set working directory of R as the newly made folder by my project!
So I want to run a command through cmd(command prompt) to make it happen.

Already tried 
`$Rscript setwd("path")` 
but didn't work!!!!!!

Comment: could you send the command you tried and the output you got? what do you mean by not able to change working directory ?As far as i know the current session opened by command prompt cannot be modified using another platform like R. "setwd" is the usual command to change the working directory within the R session

Comment: Did you really not use parentheses? I would expect `setwd("your/path")` to work, and `setwd"path"` to be a syntax error.

Comment: sry... i used C:\Users\user>Rscript setwd("C:\Users\user\Desktop\new\0") this as cmd command

Comment: error: Fatal error: cannot open file 'setwd(C:\Users\user\Desktop\new\0)': Invalid argument

Comment: @niths4u can u suggest any other method for my problem....my problem is like this...I am using netbeans to create a project..using javascript in it.It's a machine learning project in which i have to build data using regression model using R...So for each data inputted by user I make a new folder and copy the model and user data in it..now in order to run the R file i need to set working directory as that folder...I was planning to update R file parallely copying it in the folder but it didn't work...so I thought first I should update working directory for each data..but it's not working either

Comment: You need to escape backslashes in R strings. Either use forward slashes `/` or wherever you have backslashes, double them, `\\ `. This has nothing to do with the command prompt - it is true generally.

Comment: I'd suggest closing as duplicate maybe of [Raw text strings for filepaths in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8197027/903061).

Comment: @Gregor getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

A) Set the environment variable R_HOME

In Ubuntu:

1. `sudo nano /etc/environment`
2. Add the line: `R_HOME="my/working/directory"`

B) Put it in the file ~/.Rprofile which runs when R starts up

1. `sudo nano ~/.Rprofile`
2. Add the line `setwd("/my/working/directory")`