# Error: '\P' is an unrecognized escape in character string (<input>:1:33)

Tags: r

I am new to r and trying to import multiple csv files into the r studion I was trying to get multiple csv files uploaded and merged into one single year in r studio but keep displaying error message. Below is a sample of the code I used. Thank you.

```
bike_ride <-list.files(path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\Capstone req. data"
                        pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE) %＞% 
  lapply(read_csv) %＞%  # Store all files in list
  bind_rows     
Result: Error: '\P' is an unrecognized escape in character string (<input>:1:33)
```

Comment: Use forward slashes

Comment: You might find these helpful. R expects unix/linux style paths with forward slashes, but windows paths use backslashes. You can either convert the path manually to swap the slashes or make them double (the first one "escaping" for the 2nd), or use "raw strings," added to R a few years ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197027/raw-text-strings-for-file-paths-in-r  and https://josiahparry.com/posts/2023-01-19-raw-strings-in-r.html

Comment: @user2554330, good point, I've edited my comment to remove that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

As @stefan_aus_hannover suggested, use forward slashes.

```
bike_ride <-list.files(path="C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS/MSSQL/Backup/Capstone req. data"
                        pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE) %＞% 
  lapply(read_csv) %＞%  # Store all files in list
  bind_rows
```

Should work